# Python inline if statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

Could someone help me with the syntax of the following or tell me if it is possible or not? As I am going to modify the `if ... else ...` condition. I don't want to add duplicated values in the list, but I got a `KeyError`.

Actually, I am not familiar with this kind of statements:

```
twins[value] = twins[value] + [box] if value in twins else [box]
```

what does this exactly mean?

Sample code

```
#dictionary
twins = dict()                  
#iterate unitlist
for unit in unitlist:                                              
    #finding each twin in the unit
    for box in unit:                            
        value = values[box]                               
        if len(value) == 2: 
            twins[value] = twins[value] + [box] if value in twins else [box]
```

I modified the condition

```
#dictionary
twins = dict()                  
#iterate unitlist
for unit in unitlist:                                              
    #finding each twin in the unit
    for box in unit:                            
        value = values[box]                               
        if len(value) == 2:                            
            if value not in twins:                    
                twins[value] = twins[value] + [box]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This

```
twins[value] = twins[value] + [box] if value in twins else [box]
```

is functionally equivalent to this:

```
if value in twins:
    tmp = twins[value] + [box]
else:
    tmp = [box]
twins[value] = tmp
```

Comment: Actually "twins[value] = tmp" should be placed inside if-else. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You need to use:

```
if value in twins:                    
    twins[value] = twins[value] + [box]
else:
    twins[value] = [box]
```

or if you want to keep your `not in` condition:

```
if value not in twins: 
    twins[value] = [box]               
else:    
    twins[value] = twins[value] + [box]
```

But you could also use `dict.get` with a default to do it without the `if` completly:

```
twins[value] = twins.get(value, []) + [box]
```